# How to free unused space using UPDATE table SET column = NULL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update

I' am running this simple php script to release some space from unused mysql columns. I can't just delete them I need them to have as little space as possible.
But after I ran this script database size or table size haven't changed at all. Do I need to restart mysql or reset cache of some sort?

```
foreach($db_list as $db){
    $mysqli->query("USE `$db`;");   
    foreach($table_list as $table){
        foreach($column_list as $column){
            $update = $mysqli->query("UPDATE $table SET $column = NULL;");
        }
    }
}
```

This command shows no changes in used storage either (I ran it before and after launching php script).

```
df -h
```

Comment: run optermise afterwards (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimize-table.html) and depending on column type, this may make no difference. Actually empty to null could use up more space. but why not just remove the whole column\table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine I just thought that it would free significantly more space.